# Docker Containers - User Data

Tags: docker

If you set up an app stack with Docker (either in one container or as a sequence of linked containers) sooner or later there will be a need to serialize user data - e.g. the database.  From what I have seen thus far this can be done in two ways

- Map volumes on the host to the Docker container(s) with the -v switch.
- Create a dedicated data container which is stored & restored as and when required

No issues with either of these approaches - they are easy to implement and work just fine.  However, there are a few things that are not clear to me:

- When a data container is actually alive where the data actually being written. For example do the files written to the /var/lib/mysql folder inside that container end up somewhere on the host's file system?
- What are the risks of mapping a host system sub folder as a volume on to the Docker container bearing in mind that now the container's user is able to write directly to the host's file system
- Finally, is there a simple way to limit the size of that mapped volume?

I'd much appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You will get an answer on your first question by examining carefully the output of the `docker inspect <your running container>`, in particular the `Volumes` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When a data container is actually alive where the data actually being written. For example do the files written to the /var/lib/mysql folder inside that container end up somewhere on the host's file system?

The volumes which are not mounted from the host are stored here:
/var/lib/docker/volumes/

> What are the risks of mapping a host system sub folder as a volume on to the Docker container bearing in mind that now the container's user is able to write directly to the host's file system

As long as your container is not run as [privileged](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration) i.e. with the --privileged=true flag your container is not able to access devices and is locked out from several sensitive parts of the host fs. Secondly by default all processes inside docker run as root, this given them a lot of privileges inside container and since docker does not guarantee secure sand boxing yet potentially someone who hacks a process inside your container can break out. Therefore you should use the docker [USER](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#user) command in your docker file or the [-u](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#user) flag to run your processes as an alternate user.

> Finally, is there a simple way to limit the size of that mapped volume?

You have to do it outside docker, maybe by creating a separate logical drive and sizing it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by not privileged & not using root user? Just blocking access to bash & sudo from within the container or something else?

Comment: Added a little more detail and some links for you

Comment: Thanks @Usman Ismail.  I cannot upvote your answer again so I have upvoted your comment. So you are suggesting that safe practice would be to, say, create a dedicated user for Docker containers in the host machine and then start up the container with docker run -u <dedicated-docker-user>?